# How to create Cassius Mixin

Tags: haskell, yesod

How can I create a CSS mixin with Cassius (from Yesod Haskell Web Framework) ?

For instance, this code:

```
transition val = [cassiusMixin|
-webkit-transition: #{val}
-moz-transition: #{val}
-ms-transition: #{val}
-o-transition: #{val}
transition: #{val}
|]
```

does not work because `cassiusMixin` does not exist.

Is there a way to create a mixin with cassius?

If not, is cassius a limited version of lucius?

Comment: Do you have `import Text.Cassius` in your program?

Comment: Yes, but the `cassiusMixin` function does not seem to exist (https://www.fpcomplete.com/hoogle?q=cassiusMixin).

Comment: Ah - it seems to have last appeared in `hamlet-0.5.1.2` released in 2010. There is a QuasiQuoter called `cassius` in the `shakespeare` package, but no `cassiusMixin`.

Comment: Looks like it just reappeared in the latest shakespeare package: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/shakespeare-2.0.3/docs/Text-Cassius.html